# Raspbian broken bootloader package

Tags: raspbian, apt, packages, bootloader

I've just tried to update my Raspberry Pi 4 and am getting the error:

```
Unmet dependencies: libraspberrypi0 : Depends: raspberrypi-bootloader ( = 1.20210108) but 1.20201022 is installed
```

Running the suggested `apt --fix-broken install` command also fails.

I also get the above error about the bootloader when trying to install any other packages.

This image shows both commands being run and the errors they produce. (Apologies for it not being a screenshot. I literally can't install a package to take a screenshot because of this error):

I've highlighted the parts I've mentioned above.
Any suggestions? I've tried everything I can find online, and I'm a bit of a Linux noob so I have no idea what else to try.
[image: terminal]

**Edit**

`mount | grep boot` output:

```
/dev/mmcblk0p6 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

**Edit 2**

`dmesg` snippet

```
[    4.619097] brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.raspberrypi,4-model-b.txt failed with error -2
[    4.858933] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    4.876959] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Mar 23 2020 02:19:54 version 7.45.206 (r725000 CY) FWID 01-88ee44ea
```

Comment: I can only see a very fuzzy picture. Can't make out what it says. Please upload something with a higher resolution

Comment: @Dirk should be fixed now, apparently, the stackexchange android app really doesn't like images

Comment: At a glance it looks like the boot partition is mounted read-only, which fouls up that update.

Comment: @goldilocks Can I do anything about that?

Comment: Try `sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot`.  If that doesn't work, edit the output from `mount | grep boot` into the question.

Comment: @goldilocks seems that command had no effect. I've added the output you requested

Comment: It's not what it might have been then -- if there was some issue mounting that partition, the system tries to remount it read-only (which is what `errors=remount-ro` refers to, see `man mount`).  But it is still ostensibly `rw` so it is not that simple.  Unless the whole root fs is that way: Can you write stuff to the SD card at all?

Comment: Yeah, I can `pscp` stuff from my windows pc onto the pi in the home directory just fine

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text or screenshots. Instead copy the text direct into the question: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5014688).

Comment: Could you run `dmesg` to check if you have FS errors in the kernel log?

Comment: @Jack "seems that command had no effect" Have you tried creating a file in `/boot`? `touch /boot/test_file.txt`. Also, this seems to be a common issue related to hardware errors. `errors=remount-ro` means that if there's anything* wrong with the disk, mount read-only. Try another SD card, power supply, and/or check if there are any shorts on the pin headers. Make sure everything is good, then reboot. Let us know how that goes. [Source](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/issues/26#issuecomment-7895720)

Comment: @Elektordi see Edit 2, that's the only thing in there that looks like an error.

Comment: @PNDA I do get a "read-only file system" error when trying to create a file in /boot. Unfortunately I don't have any spare parts to swap out for testing so I'll try everything else first

Comment: @Jack Have you tried good 'ol Windows Check Disk? `/boot` is FAT32 and should show up as a normal drive when the SD card is plugged into a PC. It might "simply" be a file system error. I'm assuming you're using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just booted the Pi into recovery mode and re-installed Raspbian from NOOBs and that fixed whatever the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have a filesystem error on your `/boot` filesystem, and the `errors=remount-ro` option in your `fstab` makes it read-only when you try to write on it.

Confirm by running `mount` after the failed install command and checking the effective mount option for `/boot`. If it's indeed read-only, unmount it and try to fix the errors with `dosfsck` or by plugging the SD card in a Windows computer and scanning the disk there.

Comment: I ran mount and it does indeed show /boot as read-only. I've removed the sd card and run chkdsk on all volumes that showed up, it found no problems on any of them